# Trying to parse JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

This is my json response but when I am trying to decode the Json string I got the NULL error. When i fix the same json output in online decode it works properly. What is the problem here? I can't fix the error.

```
{
  "amount": 474,
  "created": 1414385307,
  "currency": "usd",
  "id": "-snip-",
  "livemode": false,
  "paid": true,
  "refunded": false,
  "disputed": null,
  "captured": true,
  "description": null,
  "statement_description": null,
  "failure_message": null,
  "failure_code": null,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "customer": "-snip-",
  "invoice": null,
  "refunds": {
    "data": [],
    "total_count": 0,
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/charges/-snip-/refunds",
    "count": null
  },
  "card": {
    "exp_month": 11,
    "exp_year": 2025,
    "last4": "-snip-",
    "country": "US",
    "type": null,
    "name": null,
    "id": "-snip-",
    "customer": "-snip-",
    "recipient": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_city": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "cvc_check": null,
    "fingerprint": "-snip-",
    "brand": "Visa",
    "funding": "credit"
  },
  "dispute": null,
  "balance_transaction": "-snip-",
  "metadata": {}
}
```

PHP code:

```
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array(
        'customerId' => 'Cus_id',
        'amount' => 474
);
$data = json_encode($curl_post_data);

$headers = array('Content-type: application/json');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$json=str_replace("JSON: ","","$curl_response");
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Comment: You should probably be concerned that `id` is in there; this is a public site.

Comment: Please provide your tried code

Comment: How are you using `json_decode`?
Are you using the `Associative Array` flag `(json_decode(array,flag)`?

Comment: @Rajesh kannan please post your code that you had tried .

Answer (score 2):

Pass that entire string to `json_decode()` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$str = '{ "amount": 474, "created": 1414385307, "currency": "usd", "id": "-snip-", "livemode": false, "paid": true, "refunded": false, "disputed": null, "captured": true, "description": null, "statement_description": null, "failure_message": null, "failure_code": null, "amount_refunded": 0, "customer": "-snip-", "invoice": null, "refunds": { "data": [], "total_count": 0, "has_more": false, "url": "/v1/charges/-snip-/refunds", "count": null }, "card": { "exp_month": 11, "exp_year": 2025, "last4": "-snip-", "country": "US", "type": null, "name": null, "id": "-snip-", "customer": "-snip-", "recipient": null, "address_line1": null, "address_line2": null, "address_zip": null, "address_city": null, "address_state": null, "address_country": null, "address_zip_check": null, "address_line1_check": null, "cvc_check": null, "fingerprint": "-snip-", "brand": "Visa", "funding": "credit" }, "dispute": null, "balance_transaction": "-snip-", "metadata": {} }';
$data = json_decode($str);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: It works but when I am passing the variable I got empty screen in my browser @Manisha Patel